# "Warning: ksort() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given" while sorting a 2d array with array_walk($array, 'ksort')

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, ksort

How can apply `ksort` to each element of `$counts` array? I mean simply **call this function on each row of a 2d array** (not recursively).

```
bool array_walk(array &$array, callable $funcname [,mixed $userdata = NULL])
```

I've tried `array_walk` passing the flag `SORT_NUMERIC` as user data. This gives me **a warning**:

```
$counts = array();

$counts['group1'] = array(); // Keys are timestamps but as STRING
$counts['group2'] = array(); // Keys are timestamps but as STRING
// ...

// Array + operator does a key reordering here
$counts['group1'] += $dummyData;
$counts['group2'] += $dummyData;

// .. so sort array by keys
array_walk($counts, 'ksort', SORT_NUMERIC);
```

> Warning: ksort() expects at most 2 parameters, 3 given.

What's the **third parameter**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

> Typically, funcname takes on two parameters. The array parameter's
>   value being the first, and the key/index second.
>
> If the optional userdata parameter is supplied, it will be passed as
>   the third parameter to the callback funcname.

Comment: @gremo looking at the params, no its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't actually matter if you declare your second level keys as string-typed integers, [PHP is going to convert them to integers automatically](https://3v4l.org/lA6ag).

This means that you can omit the SORT_NUMERIC or SORT_NATURAL flags in this scenario.

As for modifying the second level keys by reference, you have two basic choices.

Classic loop: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BXa1l))

```
foreach ($counts as &$row) {
    ksort($row);
}
```

---

Functional iteration with anonymous callback: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/v4bvG))

```
array_walk($counts, fn(&$row) => ksort($row));
```

---

To return a sorted copy of the array, `array_map()` is probably as clean as it gets. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/m1Hmn)

```
var_export(
    array_map(
        function ($row) {
            ksort($row);
            return $row;
        },
        $counts
    )
);
```

---

Using `array_reduce()` to enjoy a returned value *works*, but is notably more clumsy while it goes to greater effort to preserve first level keys. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YpVVY)

```
var_export(
    array_reduce(
        array_keys($counts),
        function ($result, $k) use ($counts) {
            ksort($counts[$k]);
            return $result + [$k =>$counts[$k]];
        },
        []
    )
);
```